# Electromagnetically Induced Transparrency

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-information, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-optics

In this technique, Quantum interference is introduced by driving the upper two levels of a 3-level atomic system with a strong coherent field. Under appropriate conditions, the medium becomes effectively transparent (zero absorption) for a probe field. My question is, what is the difference between probe and control field detunings?